# Customize dashed line style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to draw this style of line

[image]

For this I use method which consist of using two styles of dashed line on the same path

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{dashed with dot/.style={line cap=round,line width=3pt,dash pattern=on 0pt off 35pt},
my dash/.style={thick,dash pattern=on 20pt off 15pt}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[my dash] (0,0) to[bend right] +(4.8,2.3); 
\draw[dashed with dot] (0,0) to[bend right] +(4.8,2.3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My question is how can improve my code simply with one command without repeating the `draw` command second time. I thought, this is possible if I can customize the `dashed` line style to obtain the desired style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se, if the following solution is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
my dash/.style={thick,dash pattern=on 20pt off 15pt,
                postaction={draw, line cap=round, line width=3pt,
                            dash pattern=on 0.1pt off 34.9pt},
                }
         }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[my dash] (0,0) to[bend right] +(4.8,2.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko, `postaction` is what I need.

Comment: Interestingly, if I for `postaction` I have used your original pattern, than the first line was without of dot. So I slightly change pattern and consequently the dots aren't perfect circle even more but circle with very small difference between axes (~0.1pt). Till to now I didn't figured out, why this happen. Anyway, differences are almost invisible, I thought.